# Can the receiver input their options in html form and reply back with changes included? Is there a code for save?

Tags: html, forms, gmail, reply

I copied and pasted the html form into a gmail and it sends correctly. But when the receiver makes changes and sends it back, I do not see what they have entered.

I have sent test emails, added info to the fields and the reply does not come back including those changes.

```
<form action="mailto:kcm4designs@gmail.com">
<div class="option">
  <a href='https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMSvyTk1c9aWp5Q8H-W3YsxDrNEKpdAj47szbUXXV6fqyspSMdX01KhtCSrph0Rog?key=Q01TRy1ycHdEZWxUMWVXaGFqcGh2RjBfdnNmVjRB&source=ctrlq.org'><img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/kceW69v_XvBMiipP9OyKcXvxwUcCqBQfoieV9CDOEaJdv1lok_eAR3yFc-6yqIDwyqUvP5hjn10V9xLZ9MF7NW5_WdkY6Zo5CQvnH5BeLgNk8oGRDsVt2o2fu3NzsO94YEBT3v5o=w2400' /></a><br>
  <input type="radio" name="dapper" value="dapper"> Dapper Lil' Dude<br>
 Color: <select>
  <option value="select"></option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
  <option value="gray">Heather Gray</option>
  <option value="royal_blue">Royal Blue</option>
  <option value="aqua">Aqua</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
    </select> 
 Size: <select>
  <option value="select"></option>
  <option value="newborn">Newborn</option>
  <option value="0-3">0-3 Months</option>
  <option value="3-6">3-6 Months</option>
  <option value="6-12">6-12 Months</option>
  <option value="12-18">12-18 Months</option>
   </select><br>
<textarea name="comment" form="usrform" class="comment">Enter special requests here...</textarea>
</div>
</div><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I expected the reply email to include the choices added but it was still the blank form.

Comment: Did you ever get a working solution?